# Need to display author's email id in the "Edit post" field in wp dashboard. How do I do this?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, author

I have created a custom post type & have enabled frontend posting for the same.
I need the Edit post page to display the original author's email id. I already have "post author" displayed, but that just gives the name & username of the author. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you use `get_post` on edit page with query object. You can simply use `$post->post_author` on edit page. For example;

```
$editableid = get_query_var('id');
$postedit = get_post($editableid);
$author_id = $postedit->post_author; //Always return author ID value.

<input type="hidden" name="post_author" value="<?php echo $author_id;?>" />
```

I hope this code piece helps you.

EDIT : For email you use [the_author_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta) with your `$author_id` value.

Comment: Thanks but I found another way around. Marked this as a solution for anyone looking to do the same

Comment: I had a form on the frontend from which a user can submit the post data. I needed that author's email id to show up in the post that he created. So what I did was to add a hidden field in the form & called the user's email id into another field using a shortcode. Then on selection of a dropdown, I put in a jquery where the hidden field would be filled automatically. Sounds complicated, but worked out.